# Export only “relevant” data from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

When exporting data I only want to export the data points which are relevant. So when the graph is a straight line there should be less data points compared to a very noisy signal.

When there is no MATLAB function solving my problem I already made the follow thoughts about a user made function:

The function would go through the array looking at three points at the same time and making a linar regression. If the accuracy is above a certain threshold the function would delete the middle point (in a copy of the original array).

The problem did arrise when I tried to export a graph to LaTeX and I went over the data limitation. In the signal there are only a few very important high peaks I want to see. The rest is quite straight.

This is a very quick demonstration script to visualize the problem. For the first part of the signal fewer points are required to show the signal properly,but the more to the right the more points are needed, which has nothing to with my signal.

Update: I programmed an MVP of an algorithm myself which "works". Unfortunately it is not adaptive. So if I change the number of input points it seizes to work. Gonna start improving it now.

Update2: It doesnt work. Mistake is on my side. Still shows the idea.

```
clear

x = linspace(0.1,10,1000);

y = sin(x.^2);

hold on

%plot(x,y)

x_new = x;
y_new = y;

for n = 2:999

expected(n) = (y(n+1)-y(n-1))/2+y(n-1);

p(n)=y(n)/expected(n);

if(p(n) > 0.99 && p(n) < 1.01);

del(n)=n;
else
del (n)=1;

end

end 

del (1)=1;

x_new(del) = [];
y_new(del) = [];

plot(x_new,y_new);
```

Comment: You could use the derivative of the signal to determine when the signal is changing slowly, and undersample those parts. Try and plot `d = abs(diff(y) ./ diff(x));` with your code.

Comment: I had this idea too,but filtering the data is the hard part not to decide wheter a data point is relevant or not. At least in my opinion.

Comment: Oh @Zep you would need the curvature by the way not the slope as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a very good solution! The idea came me in the digital picture analysis lecture. The result is a algorithm which finds the biggest error and the sets a data point there. It goes on till the a minimum error is reached. Also the total amount of data points could be set. Im planning on turning this into a function with several options. Also this technique can be applied to 3D arrays, too!

Keep in mind that the code is not at all optimized, but a first working example!

[image]

```
clear
clc

x = linspace(0.1,10,1000);
y = sin(x.^2);

rel(1,1) = x(1);
rel(1,2) = x(length(x));
rel(2,1) = y(1);
rel(2,2) = y(length(y));

max_err = 0.1;

while true

    err = abs(interp1(rel(1,:),rel(2,:),x)-y);

    [~,n] = max(err);

    if err(n) < max_err
       break 
    end

    [~,m] = min(abs(x(n)-rel(1,:)));

    rel=    [[rel(1,1:m-1) x(n) rel(1,m:end)];
            [rel(2,1:m-1) y(n) rel(2,m:end)]];

    rel = transpose(sortrows(transpose(rel)));

end


plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(rel(1,:),rel(2,:))
plot(x,err)
hold off
grid on

legend('y','relevant','error')
```

I also created a github repo for anyone interested:
https://github.com/JulianWgs/get_relevant_data

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's sub-optimal attempt, based on a threshold of the second derivative:

```
%Generate test data
x = linspace(0.1,10,1000);
y = sin(x.^2);
hold all;plot(x,y);plot(x,y,'.')
%Params to change
loLim = -1;hiLim = 1;MovWind = 100;
linRatioToChange = 0.6;
numInds2Skip = 4;

rateY = gradient(gradient(y));%Second order derivative, threshold method
rateY_scaled = (rateY-movmin(rateY,MovWind)).*(hiLim-loLim)./(movmax(rateY,MovWind)-movmin(rateY,MovWind)) + loLim; %VERY dubious scaling of derivative

logIdx2Change = abs(rateY_scaled) < linRatioToChange; %apply threshold
%Check interp regions: figure;plot(x,y);hold all;plot(x(logIdx2Change),y(logIdx2Change))
x2Change = x(logIdx2Change); %values to downsample
y2Change=y(logIdx2Change);
newX = x2Change(1:numInds2Skip:end);
newY = interp1(x2Change,y2Change,newX); %Downsample

logIdx2Keep = ~logIdx2Change; %Old values to keep 
x2Keep = x(logIdx2Keep);
y2Keep = y(logIdx2Keep);

[combinedX,sortMap] = sort([x2Keep,newX]); %combine old and downsampled, not perfect but maybe good enough
combinedY = [y2Keep,newY];
combinedY = combinedY(sortMap);

plot(combinedX,combinedY);plot(combinedX,combinedY,'o')
```

So, it doesn't work great at the beginning of the signal, but gets pretty good afterwords. You can see the new purple data points skip some original, yellow data points in the detected linear regions.

[image]

Comment: Depends on the changeable parameters `linRatioToChange` and `numInds2Skip`. The above was 675, down from 1000.

Comment: Thats not much. If you would use 675 data points linearily you would probably get a better result. (Btw tried the same idea and got to the same result).

Comment: It all depends on how many points you want to remove/change. For example, `linRatioToChange = 0.8; numInds2Skip = 16;` gives 415 points, and you can still go down.